# apache james : mail server

Tags: java, mail-server, james

The following is my code.
This executed successfully. But I didn't see any mail in my inbox
Anybody please help.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
public class SendMail {
      public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {


        String fromAddress = "testmail@gmail.com";   
        String toAddress = "testmail@gmail.com";        
        Properties properties = new Properties();     
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");     
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");     
        properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp"); 


        try             
        {         
            properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);         
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress));         
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toAddress));          
            message.setSubject("Email from our JAMEs");         
            message.setText("hiiiiii!!");         
            Transport.send(message);          
            System.out.println("Email sent");     
        }     
        catch (MessagingException e)     
        {        
            e.printStackTrace();     
        } 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to either login and send over one of:

- POP
- IMAP
- Gmail API

or you can use a domain you control, at the moment you are trying to send as `gmail.com`, and being ignored because it knows your IP is not allowed to send as `gmail.com`, because of SPF, which limits spam by setting who can send as which domains

[SPF (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework)